# Repeating the same process for the whole dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Given DataFrame df:

```
        1           1.1     2           2.1     ...     1600      1600.1
    0   45.1024     7.2365  45.8769     7.1937          34.1072   8.4643
    1   43.1024     8.9645  32.5798     7.7500          33.1072   9.3564
    2   42.1024     6.7498  25.1027     7.3496          26.1072   6.3665
```

I did the following operation: I chose first`(1 and 1.1)` couple and created an array. Then I did the same with following couple `(2 and 2.1)`.

```
x = df['1']
y = df['1.1'] 
P = np.array([x, y])
```

and

```
q = df['2']
w = df['2.1']
Q = np.array([q, w])
```

Final operation was:

```
Q_final = list(zip(Q[0], Q[1]))
P_final = list(zip(P[0], P[1]))
```

Now I want to do it for the whole dataset. But it will take a lot of time.  Any idea how to iterate this in a short way?

EDITED

After all I'm doing

```
df = similaritymeasures.frechet_dist(P_final, Q_final)
```

So I want to get a new dataset (maybe) with all columns combinations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way is to use `agg` across axis 1

```
def f(s):
  s = iter(s)
  return list(zip(s,s))

agg = df.agg(f,1)
```

Then to retrieve, use `.str`. For example,

```
agg.str[0] # P_final
agg.str[1] # Q_final
.
.
.
```

---

Also, can `groupby` across `axis=1`, assuming you want every couple of columns

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns))//2, axis=1).apply(lambda s: s.agg(list,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to create 1600 individual variables. Store this in a container, like a `dict`, where the keys reference the original column handles:

```
{idx: list(zip(gp.iloc[:, 0], gp.iloc[:, 1])) 
  for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1)}
# or 
{idx: [*map(tuple, gp.to_numpy())] 
  for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1)}
```

#### Sample

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randint(1,10,(5,6))))
df.columns = ['1', '1.1', '2', '2.1', '3', '3.1']

#   1  1.1  2  2.1  3  3.1
#0  7    4  8    5  7    3
#1  7    8  5    4  8    8
#2  3    6  5    2  8    6
#3  2    5  1    6  9    1
#4  3    7  4    9  3    5

{idx: list(zip(gp.iloc[:, 0], gp.iloc[:, 1])) 
  for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1)}

#{'1': [(7, 4), (7, 8), (3, 6), (2, 5), (3, 7)],
# '2': [(8, 5), (5, 4), (5, 2), (1, 6), (4, 9)],
# '3': [(7, 3), (8, 8), (8, 6), (9, 1), (3, 5)]}
```